# Rufus uefi mode bootable ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Hi I am using windwows 7 alongside debian. My hard drive is in below format

```
dev/sda1/   ntfs 100 MB
unallocated      58GB   //first free space
dev/sda2    ntfs 315GB //My windows 7 C:
dev/sda3    extednded
dev/sda5    ntfs 300GB //My windows 7 D:
unallocated      51GB  //second free space
dev/sda6   swap  5GB
```

Now I want to install Ubuntu to second unallocated 51GB free space. Let me explain my before expirience. Before I installed debian into first 58GB free space(debian iso was made bootable by same rufus.), and in the second 51GB free space manjaro linux was there(not important) And while installing debian I remember installer gave the same efi system partion warning but I ignored the warning, finished installation. After rebooting grub came and there were only debian and manjaro but no winodws 7(debian's partition was first free space, but I dont remember wether I chose **dev/sda1** or **dev/sda HITACHI DISK 750 GB** as **grub boot loader**). Ok at that time I could not enter windows 7 but I entered debian and run this command

```
sudo update-grub
```

and the problem solved I could enter windows 7 grub includes it.
Now I am going tell you these days scenario. I decided to  switch to ubuntu and deleted debian and manjaro (with **Gparted**) and decided to install Ubuntu on second unallocated 51GB free space(second) it stays below windows and first free space. Now **here is the problem** I made my installation media with Rufus it makes usb UEFI mode. But my system uses legacy BIOS. In the above I have swap and installed ubuntu on second free space. Same efi system partition warning appeared as I expected but this time error did not allow me to continue installation as it did in debian installation. It tells me it needs **efi system partition**. So I created 250MB **EFI system partion** before second free space, then used remaining free space as  *ext4 linux system*. Now warning is gone and installation is completed succesfuly. After rebooting the grub menu did not appear instead Ubuntu system booted. **I need my windows**. Everything is in place I just need **Grub menu** to reach my systems help. Just curiousity: If I format that 100MB ntfs to efi and install Ubuntu onto the first free space could problem be solved?

Comment: The Ubuntu ISO by default is both BIOS & UEFI bootable. The choice is normally made from UEFI boot menu when booting flash drive. But it looks like Rufus lets you create either an UEFI using gpt bootable flash drive or a CSM(UEFI) using MBR bootable flash drive. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. Just be sure to create in MBR/CSM boot mode. With BIOS only install grub to a drive like sda. Installing grub into a NTFS partition will break Windows.

Comment: I am sure I chose MBR/CSM

Comment: Does UEFI still give two boot options for flash drive. One should clearly be UEFI:PMAP and other PMAP. My system uses PMAP, some just use name or label on flash drive. The one without the UEFI:PMAP or just PMAP is BIOS boot. Some UEFI clearly show UEFI boot options separately from CSM/Legacy/BIOS boot options.

Comment: The problem is my Windows 7 is using legacy mode but Ubuntu installation forces me to make partition called efi in size 250MB. But I need Ubuntu in legacy mode. I dont know how to achieve that. Can I install Ubuntu with just /(root) and swap  partitions without efi.

Comment: No, in my Bios menu my usb is shown as UEFI:KINGSTON sth like that.

Comment: then you should have a Kingston boot entry. If you have Secure Boot on, you cannot boot in Legacy mode. And you may need to change UEFI settings for USB ports, full use, boot or similar USB  settings, seems to vary by vendor.

Comment: One last thing there is one more option in advanced section in Rufus which is "Add fixes to old BIOSes". What does that mean? Should I check it when I prepare bootable does legace mean old BIIOS? Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101954/discussion-between-maksat-yalkabov-and-oldfred).